# How can sqlpackage.exe perform schema compare only on stored procedures?

Tags: sqlpackage

In VS 2012, the schema compare tool let's users compare only "stored procedures" by selecting the option "stored procedures" as the application scoped object.

Is there a way to perform schema compare only on the selected schema object using SqlPackage.exe?

Comment: exclude signature does not work if you have a signed object

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have a look at the latest documentation. They have added a `/p:ExcludeObjectTypes={string}` property and you can specify a semi-colon delimited list.

Just add all Object Types except Stored Procs.

Example `/p:ExcludeObjectTypes=Tables;Views;`

**Valid object type names are Aggregates**

- ApplicationRoles
- Assemblies
- AsymmetricKeys
- Audits
- BrokerPriorities
- Certificates
- ClrUserDefinedTypes
- Contracts
- Credentials
- CryptographicProviders
- DatabaseAuditSpecifications
- DatabaseRoles
- DatabaseTriggers
- Defaults
- Endpoints
- ErrorMessages
- EventNotifications
- EventSessions
- ExtendedProperties
- Filegroups
- FileTables
- FullTextCatalogs
- FullTextStoplists
- LinkedServerLogins
- LinkedServers
- Logins
- MessageTypes
- PartitionFunctions
- PartitionSchemes
- Permissions
- Queues
- RemoteServiceBindings
- RoleMembership
- Routes
- Rules
- ScalarValuedFunctions
- SearchPropertyLists
- Sequences
- ServerAuditSpecifications
- ServerRoleMembership
- ServerRoles
- ServerTriggers
- Services
- Signatures
- StoredProcedures
- SymmetricKeys
- Synonyms
- Tables
- TableValuedFunctions
- UserDefinedDataTypes
- UserDefinedTableTypes
- Users
- Views
- XmlSchemaCollections

Comment: Thanks Eugene, Sorry for the delay. Let me try the solution

Comment: Found the docs as of 7/21 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.dac.objecttype?view=sql-dacfx-150

Comment: I want to exclude specific table from being update when deploy to database through DACPAC file from azure pipelines .. Is it possible ?

Comment: @TahamiRizwan I don't think its possible but have a look at this question/answer https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/110957/excluding-a-specific-table-from-a-ssdt-deploy